# VLC Player on Apple TV cannot browse shared folder on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, appletv, vlc

I have VLC player installed on Apple TV. I can see my Windows 7 x64 machine (with SMB suffix after its name) when I'm browsing local network in VLC Player. But when I'm trying to open it I can see only "Empty Folder" despite I have shared folders on this machine which are visible for other computers. Meanwhile, I can browse files and folders on Linux machine with Samba installed without any problems. I suppose I should change some settings on Windows machine but have no idea what exactly. Now I have

```
Network Discovery Turned On
File and printer sharing Turned On
Public Folder sharing Turned On
Sharing for Devices use 40- or 56-bit encryption Turned On
```

Permissions to shared folders set Read / Write for Everyone. Guest account is enabled on the Windows machine.

Comment: and works fine on iOS right?